# Probably easy to fix: Invalid argument type 'void' to unary expression

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

I am new to Objective C and trying to make a basic map application in Xcode. I keep getting this error on `(void)mapView` method,

```
Invalid argument type 'void' to unary expression
```

Here is my code,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
self.mapView.delegate = self;
}

//H+ adding to have scale adjusted
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 800, 800);
    [self.mapView setRegion:[self.mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];

}
```

What is causing this?

Comment: **viewDidLoad** function need "}". But Xcode have notice at **mapView** function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the closing brace (`}`) on your `viewDidLoad` function. Corrected, it should look like this (see the line with the `THIS!!!` comment):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.mapView.delegate = self;
} // <-- THIS!!!

//H+ adding to have scale adjusted
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 800, 800);
    [self.mapView setRegion:[self.mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];
}
```

As a result of the missing brace, the compiler thinks that your `mapView:didUpdateUserLocation` function definition is an expression within the `viewDidLoad` function, not a function definition. I'm guessing that's probably not what you intended.

Comment: that fixed the error, but now getting a crash each time, and Xcode keeps popping up and switching to
    @autoreleasepool {
            return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil,     NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));

with the tag next to it of 
    Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Comment: @Hweins01: that most likely indicates a segmentation fault somewhere in your code. Unfortunately, it's very hard to diagnose based only on the information you've given. It's most likely a zombie object getting messaged, so I'd recommend giving the zombie instrument a try to see if you can track down the culprit. If you've tried that and **really** can't find the cause of the problem by yourself, then you *might* consider posting a new question.